# document.location.protocol returns empty value in javascript on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios

I am developing a .NET MVC mobile web app.

In javascript, I have a code to read value of "document.location.protocol" to form another redirect url.

However,  "document.location.protocol" returns empty value on iOS devices. Same works fine on android devices.

Why this is happening? How to resolve this?

Thanks,
Anuya

Comment: If you switch to `window.location.protocol`, does it make a difference?

Comment: @epascarello its not  working.. It does not make any  difference

Comment: Does `window.location.href` return the full URL including protocol?